# zipInputStream.getNextEntry() always return null from stream that created from byte[]

Tags: groovy, zipinputstream, boomi

Good day!

I have soap response message that contatined binary zip file. It looks like:
[binary response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieNoK.png)

I try to parse zip-file:

```
byte[] bin = ExecutionUtil.getDynamicProcessProperty("binary").getBytes(); 
logger.warning("binary "+bin);
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(bin));
logger.warning("zipStream "+zipStream+" nextEntry "+zipStream.getNextEntry());
```

`ExecutionUtil.getDynamicProcessProperty("binary").getBytes();`   -  this row make byte[] from string which contain binary from soap response.
When I try to test `zipStream.getNextEntry()` always return null.

I try to make

```
byte [] byteZip= child.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(newByteArrayInputStream(byteZip) or .Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

but I always have same result.

How I can get Entries from zipFile?

Comment: What you have in your image is not binary. It's text. And this text is most probably produced by base64-encoding the binary zip content. So you need to base64-decode it, and then open a zip input stream on the result.

Comment: JB Nizet,

Thanks, it works!!